# Enter a link inside a note section in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

In the following Sphinx Code how can you make both lines to appear with the same indentation? Also how can I configure the hyperlinks to be correctly placed and not as plain text only?

```
.. notes::
    Official Python website: https://www.python.org/

    PySide: Python Bindings for Qt: http://qt-project.org/wiki/pyside
```

Is there a better way to implement it on Sphinx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this should work. Notice the empty line after `..note ::`

```
.. note::

    * `Official Python website <https://www.python.org/>`_
    * `PySide: Python Bindings for Qt <http://qt-project.org/wiki/pyside>`_
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to define links, for example:

```
`Python <http://www.python.org/>`_
```

See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#internal-hyperlink-targets

As for the two lines under notes: you separated them with a blank line, so they will be interpreted as two separate paragraphs.